# When toggling fullscreen on MB Pro Retina 15 - a red bar appears

Tags: osx

I experience a red bar appearing right on top of my screen everytime I toggle fullscreen on. In addition to that the mouse seems to be shifted by about 50 pixels(the height of the red bar appearing in the top). For example I can click on a button while placing the mouse 30 pixels above the button.

When I exit fullscreen it disappears.

My machine is a 2016 MB Pro retina 15. The machine is running OSX High Sierra version 10.13.3 and Blender version is 2.79 2017-09-11.

[image: A red bar appears every time after fullscreen is toggled]

I'm helpful for any insights.

creased.

Comment: Isn't that just the last line of the *Info* window output?

Comment: yes that should be an error report you recently got. just resize the info header. (The Info header is also a window type)

Comment: It seems impossible to interact with the info header, because of the second part of the problem: The mouse-shift by 50 pixels(see question).  Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to resize the blender window to a smaller height. And toggle fullscreen after the window height has been decreased.